# Access data from extension after asynchronous messaging between background and content

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, promise, messaging

So, I try to do the following things in a chrome extension :

- from my panel extension, click on a button that runs a background function
- the background function updates a tab, then send a message to content
- the content receive the message, the content wait for the user click on the page then send to background an associative array with the clicked data
- background receives the data

So at this point, everything works fine. But the problem is that I need to access from my panel extension the data received by the background. I access the array of data by making a response[rowStructure] but console send me :

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: rowStructure is not defined

An that's weird, because it's the background that informs me of this message that concerns the panel :

[image]
So again, problems with Promises, as I always have since looooong weeks ;)

**Panel extension :**

```
selectElementsButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    background.updateTab(originalTabId, originalTabUrl)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("originalTab update : " + response);
            if (response === 'complete') {
                var dataArray = {"rows" : level.rows, "rowId" : rowId};
                return background.sendMessageToTab(originalTabId, "selectContent", dataArray);                    
            }
        })
        .then(function (response2) {
            console.log("response2 :");
            // **NO PROBLEM HERE :**
            console.log(response2);
            // **BUT PROBLEM HERE :**
            console.log("rowStructure : " + response2[rowStructure]);
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Background :**

```
function updateTab(tabId, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        chrome.windows.update(originalWindowId, {
            focused: true
        });
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
            "active": true,
            url: url
        }, function (tab) {
            console.log("tab with id " + tab.id + " updated");
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function tabUpdatedListener(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
                if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
                    resolve('complete');
                    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(tabUpdatedListener);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

function sendMessageToTab(tabId, action, dataArray) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            action: action,
            dataArray: dataArray
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.response === 'ok') {
                console.log("response : ");
                console.log(response.responseData);
                resolve(response.responseData);
            } else 
                reject('failed');
        });
    });
}
```

**Content :**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("message from bg : " + message.action + " with data :");
        console.log(message.dataArray);
        switch (message.action) {
            case "selectContent":
                alert("Sélectionnez les lignes à récupérer");
                selectRows(message.dataArray["rows"], message.dataArray["rowId"])
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("response : ");
                    console.log(response);
                    sendResponse({
                        response: "ok",
                        responseData: response
                    });
                });
                break;
        }
        // asynchronous response
        return true;
    }
);
```

Comment: `response2[rowStructure]` should be `response2.rowStructure` because that's how you access a literal property in JS. Also, accessing functions from another window context directly may impede garbage collection in Chrome or cause "dead objects" in FF so usually it's best to not do it and instead just load a shared js file with utility functions both in the popup and the background scripts.

Comment: As always, thanks wOxxOm for your perfect answer : response2.rowStructure works perfectly ! But for the second answer, do you mean that I shouldn't access background's functions by chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() ? Instead I should put all my messaging functions in a utility js file, shared by background (declared in manifest) and popup (declared in popup.html) ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Cross-window direct access is really needed only in edge cases like accessing huge objects or to avoid messaging in some video/media-related apps where even 1ms counts.

Comment: Ok. I did that because I saw it in some posts ... But I think the question was only "how to access backgrounds functions from popup ?" ;) So you also validate to declare the utility js file in manifest for background, and in popup.html before other js files calls for popup ?

Comment: That's how it's usually done, yes.

Comment: ok. many thanks again !